# What is the difference between declaring a member in the extended interface versus in the implementation?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++, private-members, class-extensions

I am seeing two very different behaviors for something that I thought were the exact same.

Defining my private member in the class extension like this:

```
@interface ClassA ()
@property ClassB* b;
@end

@implementation ClassA
-(ClassA*)initWithClassB:(ClassB*)newB
{
    self.b = newB;
    return self;
}

-(ClassB*)getB
{
    return self.b;
}
```

Or defining my private member in the class implementation like this:

```
@interface ClassA ()
@end

@implementation ClassA
ClassB* b;
-(ClassA*)initWithClassB:(ClassB*)newB
{
    b = newB;
    return self;
}

-(ClassB*)getB
{
    return b;
}
```

The way I am using this code is to create a ClassB object, initialize a ClassA object with that ClassB object, and then add the ClassA object to a mutable array

```
-(void)init
{
    self.classAList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.classAList addObject:[[ClassA alloc] initWithClassB:[self createClassB1]]];
    [self.classAList addObject:[[ClassA alloc] initWithClassB:[self createClassB2]]];
    [self.classAList addObject:[[ClassA alloc] initWithClassB:[self createClassB3]]];
}
-(ClassB)createClassB1
{
    ClassB* classB = new ClassB();
    //do some init
    return classB;
}
// Same thing fore createClassB2 and createClassB3 except with different data
```

When I use the first approach, and define my member in the interface extension, I see that each element in my mutable array is indeed what I would expect.

However, using the second approach, I see that my `ClassB* b` pointer in the `ClassA` object always ends up pointing to the most recently created `ClassB` object.  That is, once the `-(void)init` method finishes, the `ClassB` pointers in each of the `ClassA` objects points to the `ClassB` object I created in `createClassB3`

What is happening here?

I should also mention that the ClassB object is a C++ object and this is a an objective-c++ class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second snippet, `b` is just a global variable at file scope. The fact that it's inside of the `@implementation ... @end` is irrelevant. It is not an instance variable nor a property.

Comment: I noticed when I put `b` in `{ }` within the `@implementation...@end` I get the same behavior as the first approach, is this why?

Comment: Yes. Instance variables are always within braces in an `@interface` or `@implementation`. Note that instance variables and properties (which is what `b` is in your first snippet) are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

With the second approach you're creating a global variable, meaning it's not related to any instance of ClassA, so you will always have one and the same instance of *b pointing to the same object in memory. So anytime you change the value of the *b you're changing the object in memory at which the b variable is pointing, but never creating a new one; to understand it better you're basically initialising every ClassA object with the same ClassB variable (which is *b), so if you change the value at the portion of memory to which *b is pointing you're changing it for all the instances of ClassA created.

Hope it's clear enough.